# MVC3 Conditional Jquery Validation w/ Dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I been trying to do some jquery validation where a textfield or dropdown is validated only if a checkbox is checked.

Here is what I have:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { id = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "somePanel", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @id = "testForm" }))
{
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.SelectedValue, Model.YesNoList, " ", new { @id ="drpYesNo" })
 @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.CriminalText, new { @id = "txtSomeField" })

<input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

In the javascript I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";
    $("#testForm").validate(
    {
        rules: {
            txtSomeField: {
                required: function (element) {
                    return $("input:checkbox[name='drpYesNo']:checked").val() == 'Yes';
                }
            }
        }

    });

    $("#testForm").on("submit", function () {
        if (!$(this).valid()) {
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

I am following some of the example that are online, but can't seem to work. Any help is much appreciated. Happy Fourth of July!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a jquery validator rule you should use the **name** and not the **id** of the element you are defining the rule for. So in your case the name of your `<textarea>` is `CriminalText` and not `txtSomeField` (Obviously if this is inside an editor template the name might be different, such as for example `Foo.Bar[3].CriminalText`).

So the first step is to use the proper name:

```
rules: {
    CriminalText: {
        required: function (element) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's see the second step. In your selector you used some `:checkbox` that I cannot see anywhere in your DOM. All I can see (at least in what you have shown here) is a DropDownList and a textarea. So if you want the `<textarea>` to be required only if the user selected the value `Yes` inside the `<select>` list, here's how you could define the rule:

```
rules: {
    CriminalText: {
        required: function (element) {
            return $('#drpYesNo').val() == 'Yes';
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously assumes that you have the following option selected:

```
<select>
    <option value="Yes">Yes, of course</option>
    ...
</select>
```

And one final remark: make sure that you have not included the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script to your page as it will use Microsoft's unobtrusive library to automatically write the jQuery.validate rules based on the HTML5 data-* attributes generated by the helpers and thus completely messing up your custom rule setup.

Comment: @up: THIS! I couldn't wrap my head around what's wrong with my validation code. It was the unobtrusive script from MS. :/

Answer (score 1):

The selector here is the problem, using `input:checkbox` is for checkboxes.  Typically, jquery prefers css class names or id's.

```
required: function (element) {
  return $("#drpYesNo").val() === 'Yes';
}
```

Comment: drpYesNo is a <select /> and not a <input type="checkbox" /> this would still work?

Comment: I was thrown off by the selector "input:checkbox".